# How to test session passivation in spring

Tags: spring, session, scope

I want to use session scoped beans in my spring 3 application, and I stumbled around [this article](http://justonjava.blogspot.hk/2011/02/session-passivation-and-spring-part-1.html).

Now I would like to test whether my session beans are correctly passivated and reactivated, but how can I do this in spring? I am looking for a way to set a session-passivation timeout or a function that force the session to passivate programatically.

Comment: Very sad that no answer on that for such a long time... Struggling the problem n